# sencha touch2 icons not showing up

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

I am trying to add icons to my tab panel but the icon is not showing up , only title is working

eg.

```
   title: 'Reports',      
   iconCls: 'chart'

   title: 'My Cart',
   iconCls: 'cart'
```

for the above icon is not showing up, home and list icons are working fine,can someone please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include those icons in your SASS, and run your Compass build.

```
@include icon('cart');
@include icon('chart');
```

See the "Using the Pictos font" section of the docs for more details: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: Thank you .. I added @include in app.sass and trying to compile like this compass watch... it is showing error  compass: command not found

Comment: Installed compass and added icons...working .Thank you so much